# Java regex to remove space between numbers only

Tags: java, regex

I have some strings like:

```
String a = "Hello 12 2 3 4 45th World!";
```

I wanna concatenate numbers as: `"Hello 12234 45th World"`

By trying `a.replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d)", "")`, I got the result as:
`"Hello 1223445th World"`.

Is there any way to concatenate only numbers, not *number*+*th*?

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d+(?:\\s|$))
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/43

Comment: @YangQian How about `foo1 2 3.` Should space before `3.` be also removed?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in the look-ahead to only match numbers as whole words:

```
a.replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d+\\b)", ""))
```

[Sample code on IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Mw4K4g):

```
String a = "Hello 12 2 3 4 45th World!";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d+\\b)", ""));
```

Output:

```
Hello 12234 45th World!
```

Comment: This fails when I try to remove spaces between numbers in the string as follows: Hello 12 2 3 4 45 World!

Comment: Fixed, just `+` must be added. `System.out.println("Hello 12 2 3 4 45 World!".replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d+\\b)", ""));` --> `Hello 1223445 World!`. Inside a look-ahead, we can use `+` since they are not constrained-width, as opposed to look-behinds.

Comment: @YangQian: Please check my updated code. I believe it is all you need here. My regex will take care of situations like `Text 234 34 35 5, text` or `4566 45676 55 5.`, vks won't.